# Angular2 filtering array of objects based on an array of objects using pipe

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, lambda, filter

I'm struggling to get my head around how to filter an array of objects based on another array of objects using the angular pipe.  What i have so far is a pipe that filters based on a single argument.

I have 2 arrays, array1 and array 2, which both contain complex objects. The filtered array (array1) should only contain objects where array1.value === array2.value

My code so far:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'arrayFilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class AttributeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], filterFrom: any[]): any {
    return array.filter(item => item.value.indexOf(filterFrom[0].value) !== -1);
  }
}
```

Comment: The filtered array (array1) should only contain objects where array1.value === array2.value - comparing objects at the same index? or array1 should only have objects contained in array 2?

Comment: array1 should only contain objects that are in array2.  The comparison should be done on array1[i].value === array2[i].value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If array 1 should only contain objects that are in array 2:

```
return array.filter(item => filterFrom.some(f => f.value == item.value));
```

If array 1 should only contain objects that are in array 2 at the same index:

```
return array.filter((item, index) => item.value == filterFrom[index].value);
```

Comment: Option one works but my array has lost its order. Is there any way to filter and keep the order of array1?

Comment: So I made a mistake and the array (array1) is staying in the correct order.  My problem now is I need the order of array1 to be that of array2

Comment: +1 Almost exactly what I wanted but the opposite.  I needed to filter an array and pull out all items not within a second array.  That code is: return array.filter(item => !filterFrom.some(f => f.value == item.value));